# Is there a way to link uv's so as to tile them onto an object?

Tags: texturing, uv

Take the default cube, unwrap it and apply a texture. Looks nice; none of the textures are stretched or squished. If you go into edit mode now and select the top face of the cube and move it up or down it will look as though the texture is stretched or squished on the sides... is there a way to stop this happening? A way to link the object to the uv so as you edit the proportions the uv automatically updates the sizes automatically in proportion? In google sketchup you can tile textures so when you edit the size of a surface it just draws more or less tiles and doesn't cause stretch or compression of the textures... I'm looking for the same sort of functionality in blender.

Answer (score 2):

A convoluted way to do this would be to use the **[UV Project](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/modify/uv_project.html)** modifier and 3 empties.

In the center of the cube add an empty.
Add a second empty (empty.001) and rotate it 90 degrees on the X axis.
Add a third empty (empty.002) and rotate it 90 degrees on the Z axis.

Select your UV unwrapped cube and add a UV project modifier, assign the image texture, click the override Imabe box. Change the number of projectors to 3 and assign the empties as projectors.

[image]

Then as you modify the cube the textuere will repeat in tiles.

[image]

Comment: I admire your method, it is great for learning purposes, and your animated graphic simply blew my away. Sadly my question was not very well written and what I was hoping was for a tiling technique that could be applied to more complex objects. But thanks anyway for taking the time to show me, I appreciate it.